# Using geom_raster to visualise a dataframe of datatypes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am putting together a workflow in R that will ultimately be used to assist in migrating a series of very large databases that are similar, but frustratingly different in minor ways.

One of the things I need to be able to visualise is which variable names are present in each database, and what datatype they are.

I have reached the point where I have a summary dataframe that looks very similar to the example below.

```
category <- c("Location", "Date", "Time", "Number")
species1 <- c("character", "character", "character", "integer")
species2 <- c("integer", "integer", NA, "character")
species3 <- c("character", "posix", "posix", "integer")
species4 <- c(NA, NA, "posix", "integer")

comparison_table <- data.frame(category, species1, species2, species3, species4)
```

The `NA` values denote that this variable is not present within a specific database.

My ultimate goal was to construct a plot of coloured squares to easily identify inconsistent datatypes between the databases (for example, where dates have been recorded as integers instead of POSIX, or where latitude recorded as a character instead of an integer).

My gut tells me that the `geom_raster` in `ggplot2` should be the simplest way to achieve this, but I keep coming up short. I know that I need to define the `fill` in the aesthetic, but every attempt is met with a different error.

```
comparison_table %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = colnames(comparison_table), y = rownames(comparison_table))) +
  geom_raster()
```

A fresh pair of eyes and a less tired brain would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to re-structure your data to fit in the grammar of `ggplot`.

In `aes(x, y, fill)`, we should supply a column from `data`, which essentially tells which variable should the subsequent `geom_function()` use to display the data.

In your case, you want:

1. x-asix to be "Location", "Date", "Time", "Number", which I grouped them into the `Category` column.
2. Similarly, your y-axis would be `species`, where species1, species2, species3, species4 are grouped in this column, with it's corresponding value grouped into the `type` column.
3. Moreover, since you wish to visualise your data using `geom_raster()`, you should also tell `ggplot` to use which variable to `fill` the squares (remember to use `fill` inside `aes()` if your `fill` comes from a column).

```
library(tidyverse)

comparison_table %>% pivot_longer(!Category, names_to = "species", values_to = "type") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Category, y = species, fill = type)) +
  geom_raster()
```

[image: geom_raster]